# How to number slides in a beamer class presentation consisting of multiple parts?

Tags: beamer, numbering

I'm working on a series of presentations and uses LaTeX slides for each part. I would like to continue numbering the slides for each part according to the previous part; for example, part 1 slides numbers  from 1 to 50, part 2 slides from 51 to 100, and so on. Each part has a separate `.tex` file.

Is there any command to accomplish this?

For example, I want this file to start numbering from 50, not from 1:

```
\documentclass{beamer}      

\usetheme{Boadilla}  

\setbeamertemplate{footline{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}       

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `slides` (as a documentclass) or `beamer`? Can you show a minimal working example of what you have and where you are stuck? Are you working on completely different documents?

Comment: Sorry, I added a sample

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{beamer}      

\usetheme{Boadilla}  

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}       

\addtocounter{framenumber}{50}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
text

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

or if you want an automatic solution, give a custom label to the last frame in part 1, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}[label=lastframe]
text
\end{frame}
```

Assuming your first part is called `part1.tex` then you can do the following in your document to automatically resume the frame numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}      

\usetheme{Boadilla}  

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}       

\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\zexternaldocument*[main-]{part1}

\usepackage{refcount}

\setcounterref{framenumber}{main-lastframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   text
\end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
text

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `\setcounter{framenumber}{50}`